# Amplify GraphQL V1 to V2 migration Authorization Issues

Tags: graphql, amazon-iam, aws-appsync

I have successfully followed this tutorial [How to allow guest users to access web applications? (Amplify, AWS AppSync, Cognito & IAM)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZRJbosMAWU4)

By installing @aws-amplify/cli@8.5.1 which uses nodejs@14.x to implement a V1 API in AWS.
Note: The tutorial uses v4.37 the latest is v12.6

This is the schema;

```
type Book
  @model 
  @auth( 
    rules: [ 
      # allow admins to create, update and delete books 
      { allow: groups, groups: ["admin"] } 
      # allow all authenticated users to view books 
      { allow: private, operations: [ read ]} 
      # allow all guest users ( not authenticated ) to view books 
      { allow: public, operations: [read], provider: iam} 
    ] 
  ) { 
  id: ID! 
  title: String! 
  description: String 
  price: Float 
}
```

When I update to @aws-amplify/cli@12.6.0 , `amplify push` uses **v2** of the graphQL transformer.

With reference to the @auth rules in the schema, I can successfully log into the Cognito User Pool;

1. create and list books as an authenticated user of the admin group
2. list books as an authenticated user

I get the following error;
**Request failed with status code 401**

when I try to list books **as an unauthenticated user using IAM**

Any help in resolving this will be much appreciated?

C.

Comment: Could anybody verify that my schema is correct for v2 ?

Comment: I used `amplify status api -acm Book` to verify that the schema was correct!